# Random variables in normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Suppose that $X_1$, $X_2$ are independent $\mathcal{N}(0,4)$ random variables. Compute $P\left(X_1^2<36.84-X_2^2\right)$.

I have no idea how to start this. Do I have to do anything to the $\mathcal{N}(0,4)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First transform $X$ to a standard normal distribution: $X/2 \sim N(0,1)$. Then of course $X \sim 2Y$ where $Y$ is the standard distribution. So now we can write $X_1^2+ X_2^2$ as $$(2Y_1)^2 + (2Y_2)^2 =4 (Y_1^2 + Y_2^2)= 4 \cdot \chi^2(2) = 4 \cdot Z.$$ Where $Z \sim \chi^2(2)$. So you are looking for $P(Z < 36.84/4)$, since $P(Z < 36.84/4)= P(X_1^2 <36.84 -X_2^2)$. You can check out the $\chi^2$ distro here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, you can write the density function of the vector $(X_1,X_2)$ as the product of marginals, so
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{8 \pi}\exp(-(x^2+y^2)/8)$$
Then you compute
$$P(X_1^2+X_2^2 \le t^2) = \int \int_{B(0,t)} f(x,y) \, dy \, dx $$
passing to polar coordinates
$$= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^t \frac{1}{8 \pi} \exp(-r^2/8) r \, dr \, d\theta = 1 - \exp(-t^2/8)
$$
Numerical result is $1-exp(-36.84/8) \simeq 0.9899$.